# Is it possible to serialize an object into a plain text string and send it as a string then convert it back?

Tags: java

As the title says. I'm sending a message, from my server, into a proxy which is outside of my control which then sends it onto my application. All I can do is send and receive strings. Is it possible to serialize to a plain string and send in this way without an input/output stream as you would normally have?

TIA

A little more info:

```
public class myClass implements java.io.Serializable {
int h = "ccc";
int i = "bbbb";
String myString = "aaaa";
}
```

I have this class, for example. Now I want to serialize it and send it as a string inside my HTTPpost and send to the proxy, can't do anything about this stage:

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.myURL.com/send.php?msg="+msg);
```

Then receive the msg as a string on the other side and convert it back.

Is that easily done without to many other library?

Comment: You could always convert the serialization to Base64, then treat it like text -- embed in an email, etc.

Comment: Yes. If it can be described, it can be programmed.

Comment: I don't know what you "normally have", but if Input/Output stream is the case, then you can very easily convert those to String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

This is done every day using JSON and XML, just to name a few formats of strings that are easily formatted and parsed. (Read about JAXRS to know about a way to use JSON formatted strings to do this and do the transfers. Or, read about JAXB which will format as XML but doesn't halp with the communication of the strings.)

You can do it in CSV format.

You can do it in fixed with fields of characters.

Morse code isn't much of a different concept only it starts with strings and converts to short and long beeps.

The way it works is this:

1. There is some code to which you pass an object and it returns a string in a known format.
2. You send the string to the other server somehow. Some ways to send strings have limits on the length.
3. The other server receives the string.
4. Using its knowledge of the format, that other server parses out the string contents and uses it.

Some notes:

- If both servers use Java (or C# or Python or PHP or whatever) the formatting and parsing become symetrical. You start with a Java object of some type and end up with a Java object in the other JVM of the same type. *But that is not a given. You can store values in a custom POJO in one server and a Map in the other.*
- If you write code to format and parse, it seems really easy as long as the contents are simple and you don't run afoul of transmission rules. For example, if you send in the query part of an HTTP get, you can't have any ampersand characters in the string.
- If you use an existing library, you take advantage of everyone else's acquired knowlege of how to do this without error.
- If you use a standard format for the string, it is easy to explain what's going on to someone else. If your project works, a third server might want to be in the communication loop and if it's controlled by someone else ...
- Formatting is easier than parsing. There are lots of pitfalls that other people have already solved. If you are doing this to learn ways not to do things and improve your own knowledge base, by all means, do it yourself. If you want rock solid performance, use an existing and standard library and format.

Comment: Those, of course, won't serialize arbitrary objects.  (But, then again, Java serialization won't either, I guess.)

Comment: @HotLicks JSON and XML can do most object graphs if they don't have circular references. You are right about CSV and fixed width fields.

Comment: I've added an example of what I'm after to my post. Is JSON really the way to do this. Is there no pure java way of doing it?

Comment: eric-banderhide: If you don't want to use other 3rd party libraries, you can use java serialization or JAXB(usually a better option).

Comment: @user2266098 Jaxb is a 3rd party library. Its just supported by Oracle and other Java suppliers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at **XStream**. It serializes into XML, and is very simple to use.

Take a look at there [**Two Minute Tutorial**](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can use ajax to to serialize the string to a json object and have it back to the server using an ajax.post event (javascript event).

Comment: Most servers don't use JavaScript and Ajax is typically used when a browser based client does the serialization and deserializes the result.